# Why is the given code for signature generation on a character string using hash modulo returning character(0)?

Tags: r, compression, string-matching, levenshtein-distance, digest

First post on overflow, so I apologize in advance if I step out of formatiquette.

Because of a recent work assignment, I came to require the implementation of string matching across two very large character vectors. Each of these vectors is about 1M elements in length.

I have been working with Levenshtein and JW distances as metrics for similarity, however as might be expected, their O(n) complexity is directly proportional to the length of the strings being matched.

Vectorizing these distance functions over the two character vectors that I have is going to be memory intensive and time intensive, and I expect to run into buffer overflows. I tried running the distance algorithm on a small subset of these vectors and the memory space got occupied pretty heavily.

**Therefore,** I decided to generate the hash signatures of each string, so that they occupy less space and can be processed faster. The algorithm that I have followed for generating the same can be found here: [Super-Fast-Estimate-Levenshtein-Distance](https://dzone.com/articles/super-fast-estimates-of-levenshtein-distance)

Summarily, the algorithm follows these steps:

1. Intialize an array (I used a df imaginatively named **ascii**) of printable ASCII characters for signature elements.
2. Generate hash of text sub-strings using a fov value that determines the length of the substrings. (I used **"md5"**, should I use "xxhash32"; does it change things significantly?)
3. Compute the **modulo** of the integer hash over the compression value decided before implementation.
4. If it's not equal to zero, break or switch to next in the loop. If it is, return a character from the ascii dataset as: ascii[(**int.hash** %% **length(ascii)**),]
5. Loop until you reach the end of the string.
6. Return the signature.

I wrote a function trying to implement the same, but it only throws a character(0) at me. Some help in identifying the offending clause will be greatly appreciated.

The parameters for the function are:

- **x**        : String input for signature generation
- **compress** : Compression factor for the signature
- **fov**      : Substring length that will be considered in each iteration

I am providing the function code and output below:

**Code:**

```
library(Rmpfr)
library(digest)

  Sigtex <- function(x,compress,fov){  
  x <- as.character(x)  
  compress <- as.integer(compress)  
  fov <- as.integer(fov)  
  s = character()  
  for(i in 1:nchar(x)){  
  modu <- mpfr(x =digest(substr(x,i,(i+fov)), algo = "md5",serialize = F),base = 16)
    if(modu%%compress != 0){
    if(i==nchar(x)) {break} 
    else {next} } 
    else{s = paste(s,ascii[(modu%%62),],sep = "")}}  

    if(i==nchar(x)) {return(s)} 
    else {next} }
```

**Output:**

```
  >Sigtex("Simbasrteha",123,3)
  character(0)

  >Sigtex("LionKing",123,5)
  character(0)
```

Thanks again.

Comment: `modu%%compress != 0` is never `FALSE`. You can check by adding `message(modu%%compress)` before the `if` condition. So, the corresponding `else` is never executed and `s` not modified in the loop. Also, I have no idea what you believe `next` does, in particular outside of a loop.

Comment: Yes, had messed up the } while trying to format. Also, I understand that the if condition is never false, but isn't it what the algorithm is dictating on the link that I provided? 
Regardless, I have changed the code to: `if(modu%%compress != 0) {if(i==nchar(x)) {break} else {s = paste(s,ascii[(modu%%62),],sep = "")}` 
Do you think this would be a better representation?

Comment: Please don't expect me to follow the link or study complex algorithms in an area I'm not familiar with. I just pointed out what happens and also gave you a hint for debugging it yourself (there are further, more sophisticated tools available). I would probably not do this in R but in a compiled language (i.e., Rccp).

Comment: Can you point me towards those tools? Also, I assumed you had glanced over the link, but that's of course perfectly fine.

Comment: For example `help("browser")` or breakpoints in RStudio.